# What does 'shouty color' mean?

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to describe a situation where a particular color is too bright or harsh. But I don't think 'bright' and 'harsh' are the right words to use here. Is it right to replace the phrase 'too bright' with 'shouty'?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but some synonyms that came to my mind are flashy, and flamboyant and gaudy.. maybe even blatant?

Comment: And...dazzling!

Comment: A "shouty colour" could be bright red text in a black document -- implying that someone reading out loud would raise their voice at that point.  I wouldn't use it in any other sense

Comment: "Shouty" is unfamiliar to me, but sounds like a rephrasing of "[loud](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350159/what-does-loud-checks-mean-in-parading-the-town-at-night-in-loud-checks-and-a/350161#comment811174_350161)", as in "That's a pretty loud outfit you're wearing."  Though "loud" is generally applied to, eg, a checked pattern or something similar that is visually disorienting.

Answer (score 1):

There are more idiomatic ways to tie colors to adjectives of loudness.

[image: color_adjectives]

Loud as visual description:

> *loud 1.2 Vulgarly* obtrusive; flashy.  [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/loud)

Answer (score 0):

"Shouty," in this context, can mean whatever you want it to mean. It is not a generally accepted adjective in this sense.

If I read it used to describe a person, I'd understand that they were loud and brash, and possibly argumentative or with a short temper.

I'd probably have to think twice to understand what it meant with regards colour, but I could guess what it would mean.

Why not try "loud" or "brash" in this context?